# C++/CLI multiple buttons maintaining variable value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

OK let me explain my problem.

I'm working on a program where I have a button. Clicking it causes the number "1" to appear, then, after that, any further clicks will increment that value until it reaches the value of "9". (It's a string). I wrote this code which declares an int variable to 0 (Yes, this was a mistake but let me continue) then increment it and parse it to string and show it on the button text(This is the code that executes on button click):

```
private: System::Void a0_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             int i = 0;
             i++;
             a0->Text = i.ToString();
         }
```

However, as you can suspect, I did the foolishness of declaring i with 0 for each button press, so the result was that 1 was the only value showing on the button. The next thing I tried doing, was declaring i as global variable with the value of 0. However, I came to another problem. I have 82 buttons of that kind, and I'm going for the easiest sollution I can find, so sharing the i variable seemed logical,

The next problem was that if I pressed 5 times the first button, the number displayed on it would be "5" however if I pressed another button, the value wouldn't be "1" by default, it would be "6" (The value of the first button incremented by one). Basically it would inherit the value of the first.

Now I'm at a dead end. I have no idea what to do. I tried using i and i2 but I was just chasing my own tail. Is there a very easy solution to this? Keep in mind I've got 82 buttons (Yes I know it's alot) which are by default 0. When I click each one I need it to *increment by one, starting from 0*. Any ideas?

Notes: OS is Windows XP, IDE is Visual Studio 2010m using windows forms app, C++/CLI. If I forgot to mention anything post in comments and I'll add it.

Comment: A user interface with 82 buttons boggles my imagination.  Hard to decode what they are supposed to do from the question.  Add a screenshot.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I know it's alot, it's a game, and I have a 9x9 board. I don't really have any other alternative rather than buttons. Each has a simple use in my program. Each tile from the 9x9 board is a button.

Comment: Well, sure you do.  A panel with a paint event that draws a 9x9 board works too.  Now you got only one MouseDown event.  Figure out what was clicked from e->Location

Comment: I have never done that before. Do you know where I could find some documentation for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect `sender` to find out what button was clicked.

```
void anybutton_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^)
{
    Button^ btn = dynamic_cast<Button^>(sender); // or safe_cast
    int i;
    if (System::Int32::TryParse(btn->Text, i)) {
         i++;
         btn->Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```